# @XmlElement that is able to have more that on element type and only one instance

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am trying to figure out how to annotate a class variable so that it can have at most one element of a  base type - but the concrete type can be one of three different classes. Here is an example that hopefully should explain what I am trying to accomplish.

```
public class A extends Baseclass {}
public class B extends Baseclass {}
public class C extends Baseclass {}

public MyClass {

@XmlElements({
     @XmlElement(name="name1",type="A.class"),
     @XmlElement(name="name2",type="B.class"),
     @XmlElement(name="name3",type="C.class")
})
private Baseclass xyz;

...
```

}

This construct allows the xml to contain multiple elements with "name1", "name2", or "name3". JAXB evidently just takes the last element parsed and uses that one as the value for "xyz".

However, what I want is for JAXB to allow only one element of of type A, B, or C with "name1", "name2" or "name3" respectively.

The xml looks like:

```
<myElement>
    <name1></name1>
    <name1></name1>
    <name2></name2>
 </myElement>
```

In this case, the name2 element wil be assigned to the xyz variable.

But what I want is for JAXB to return an error if the above xml construct is used.

I want to allow only

```
<myElement>
   <name1></name1>
</myElement>
```

but not

```
<myElement>
   <name1></name1>
   <name1></name1>
   <name2></name2>
</myElement>
```

The javadoc for @XmlElements states that it is for lists, which seems to be why this behavior is occurring.

So, my question is:

How do I annotate "xyz" to obtain the desired behavior? @XmlAdapter or something?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use schema validation to get the behaviour you are looking for.  This is done by setting an XML schema on the `Unmarshaller` to have an error thrown if the XML does not match the XML schema:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-marshalunmarshal-schema.html

If you do not have an XML schema you can use JAXB to generate one from your domain model:

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/JAXB/GenerateSchema

`@XmlElements` corresponds to the concept of a choice structure in XML schema and will work for your use case.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/jaxb-and-xsd-choice-xmlelements.html

However, since `A`, `B`, and `C` all extend from `BaseClass` you may want to consider using `@XmlElementRef` which corresponds to the XML schema concept of substituion groups:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-substitution.html